# How to rotate labels to follow contours in Python?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, contour

I have data ([link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BwwhEMUIYGyTYV9HclR2NzZESHc/view?usp=sharing)) of the form given below:

```
Y   X 0 X 10    X 20
15  4.83    4.91    4.99
20  4.58    4.65    4.73
25  4.43    4.49    4.56
```

I am trying to plot contours of the X **label values**, in these cases 0, 10, 20 (as z in code) with x-axis as X values and y-axis as Y values. Plots are created using the code:

```
import numpy as np
import re
from matplotlib.backends.backend_pdf import PdfPages
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.cm as cm

with open('contour.dat', "r") as data:
    while True:
        line = data.readline()
        if not line.startswith('#'):
            break
    data_header = [i for i in line.strip().split('\t') if i]
_data_ = np.genfromtxt('contour.dat', skiprows = 2, delimiter = '\t')
x = _data_[:, 0]
y = _data_[:, 1:]


y_n = []
for i in range(len(data_header)):
    if data_header[i][0] == 'X':
        y_n = np.int_(np.append(y_n, i))
y_index = [data_header[i] for i in y_n]
z = []
for i in range(0, len(data_header)):
    z = np.append(z, re.findall(r"[-+]?\d*\.\d+|\d+", data_header[i]))
z = z.reshape(len(z), 1)
xm = np.tile(x, 21)
xm = np.reshape(xm,(21, 10)).T
zm = np.tile(z, 10).T

with PdfPages('./on_tau.pdf') as p_tau:
    _p_vs_tau_ = plt.figure(figsize=(5, 5))
    _p_vs_tau_.clf()
    p_vs_tau = plt.subplot(111)
    # x, y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
    surf = plt.contourf(y, xm, zm, 22, rstride=1, cstride=1, cmap=cm.gist_heat,
                           linewidth=0, antialiased=False, alpha = 1.0)
    surf1 = plt.contour(y, xm, zm, 22, colors = '#000000',
                           linewidths=0.5, antialiased=False, alpha = 1.0)
    plt.clabel(surf1, inline=1, fontsize=6)
    plt.xlim([5, 10])
    p_tau.savefig(bbox_inches='tight')
    plt.close()
```

I am trying to solve the following issues:

**1. At present all the contour labels are vertical. How can I rotate the
    labels to follow the contours?**

**2. How to change the position of the labels so that they do not overlap (as shown in figure)?**

[image]

**Additional question**

**3. How to ensure that labels are always shown on plots even if axis
    limits are changed?**

Comment: The simplest option might be to position the labels manually using the mouse. You can do this by passing `manual=True` to [`plt.clabel`](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.clabel).

Comment: What version of mpl are you using?  The label should rotate by default, see http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/contour_demo.html

Comment: I can't check your code since you didn't include your data.

Comment: I wonder if it has something to do with your rcParams. In particular, it looks like you might be rendering text using TeX. Have you tried setting `plt.rcParams['text.usetex'] = False`?

Answer (score 1):

I ran the code below in `matplotlib 1.4.3` and obtained rotated contour labels as you wanted, so, I don't know why you have that problem. For your second question, what about using less contour levels?

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.backends.backend_pdf import PdfPages
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x, y = np.pi*np.mgrid[-1:1:101j, -1:1:101j]
z = np.sin(x)*np.sin(y)

with PdfPages('./contour_plot.pdf') as p_tau:
    _p_vs_tau_ = plt.figure(figsize=(5, 5))
    _p_vs_tau_.clf()
    p_vs_tau = plt.subplot(111)
    surf = plt.contourf(y, x, z, 21, rstride=1, cstride=1, cmap="RdYlBu",
                           linewidth=0, antialiased=False, alpha = 1.0)
    surf1 = plt.contour(y, x, z, 21, colors='k', linestyles="solid",
                           linewidths=0.5, antialiased=False, alpha = 1.0)
    plt.clabel(surf1, inline=1, fontsize=6)
    plt.savefig("contour_plot.png", dpi=600)
    p_tau.savefig(bbox_inches='tight')    
    plt.close()
```

[image]